# Function to Interpolate using openmodelica

Tags: interpolation, curve-fitting, modelica, openmodelica

I have some data extracted from matlab which i want them to be accessible in openmodelica. 
The data are in the form of table of x,y and the value z. I want to create a function the reproduce the point z out of x and y, in which the function can also interpolates nicely between x and y. So basically the Modelica interpolation will have to load the table of results and do the interpolation. Is this possible ? can anyone lead me to the way ?
thanks for the help in advance.

I attached my data with this message, the first row and the first column corresponds to the x and y values respectively.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/75z2ejcjru8hiu8/data.zip?dl=0

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data, or add the data to your question?

Comment: @JamesPhillips Hii James, i added a link to my data. I was trying to do my task through the function Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable2D. I am not an expert in modelica, so if you may lead me a little bit if you have an idea  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adapt the data file according to https://doc.modelica.org/Modelica%203.2.3/Resources/helpOM/Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable2D.html, i.e., do not leave the element at position (0,0) empty. See https://gist.github.com/tbeu/2004db0f7753e69f42da39aec3a00b3d for the fix.

Then, you can load and interpolate the data using MSL v3.2.3, for example

```
model Model
  Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable2D combiTable2D(
    tableOnFile=true,
    tableName="A'_Coefficient",
    fileName="c:\\temp\\data.txt") annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-95,60},{-75,80}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression realExpression1(y=time*10) annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-140,65},{-120,85}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression realExpression2(y=time*100) annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-140,40},{-120,60}})));
  equation
    connect(realExpression1.y,combiTable2D.u1) annotation(Line(points={{-119,75},{-114,75},{-102,75},{-102,76},{-97,76}}, color={0,0,127}));
    connect(realExpression2.y,combiTable2D.u2) annotation(Line(points={{-119,50},{-114,50},{-102,50},{-102,64},{-97,64}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation(uses(Modelica(version="3.2.3")));
end Model;
```

Comment: Hii tbeu, thanks for the code above, i didn't think it was this simple. My i ask what are the function of the real expressions that you added as an input ? and in case i want to obtain the value of a point(x,y) that is not in my data, how can i do that ?

Comment: RealExpression just defines the input(s) for the table, see https://doc.modelica.org/Modelica%203.2.3/Resources/helpOM/Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression.html. You can also provide any constant values, say `realExpression1(y=3)` and `realExpression2(y=12)` to obtain the interpolated value at (3,12). Note, that in the above example bilinear interpolaion is selected. You may also switch to bivariate constant or Akima interpolation.

Comment: Yes, I got it and i have already tested different  methods of interpolation. Thank you for the information provided. My next question is : would be if its possible to implement different methods of interpolation other than that used by the Modelica library and use it in this model ?

Comment: Also, how can i convert this model into a function that can give me the value of a point, and use this function more than once with different points inside a model? That is my focus actually, because i have too many points inside my model, and i guess its a long way to put the model you provided me to get the value of the point i want.

Comment: Currently, the CombiTable2D of the Modelica Standard Library (MSL) only supports bivariate constant, bilinear or bivariate Akima interpolation. I could think of bicubic interpolation in the future, too. Support of approximation is not planned within the MSL. You might try https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/ApproxSpline if you prefer smooth spline approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 3D scatterplot of your data and a 3D polynomial surface fitted to it. Because the data has considerable surface curvature I could not find a simple approximating equation for the interpolation. Here I have used a surface polynomial with 3rd order terms, and this should extrapolate poorly outside the data bounds. For this reason I recommend using it for interpolation only.

[image: scatter]

[image: surface]

```
# taken from source code output of fitting software
a = -4.8044356996540731E+00
b = -1.7238982381056298E+00
c = 9.7121730188860766E+00
d = 2.0725836239688458E-02
f = -2.3810662793461059E+00
g = -6.8495593999129412E-05
h = 1.7294254445305737E-01
i = 2.6034147965619335E-02
j = -8.6126736653591163E-04
k = 5.8779369562417683E-05

z = a
z += b * x
z += c * y
z += d * pow(x, 2.0)
z += f * pow(y, 2.0)
z += g * pow(x, 3.0)
z += h* pow(y, 3.0)
z += i * x * y
z += j * pow(x, 2.0) * y
z += k * x * pow(y, 2.0)
return z
```

Comment: Hii James, thank you for the great answer. Can i ask what software have you used to obtain these graphs ? because i can easily obtain them in matlab, but my task to make these data accessible in "OpenModelica", and to make the interpolation or the extrapolation in a modelica language.

Comment: To answer your question, I used the "function finder" on my open source Python curve and surface fitting zunzun.com web site . Often it can find a somewhat smooth, relatively less complex approximating equation to model a data set - but in this case the data appears to have so much surface curvature that it could not find such an approximating equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plain [external table object](https://doc.modelica.org/Modelica%203.2.3/Resources/helpOM/Modelica.Blocks.Types.ExternalCombiTable2D.html), if you prefer the direct interface via function [getTable2DValue](https://doc.modelica.org/Modelica%203.2.3/Resources/helpOM/Modelica.Blocks.Tables.Internal.getTable2DValue.html). For example,

```
model Model2
  parameter Modelica.Blocks.Types.ExternalCombiTable2D tableID=Modelica.Blocks.Types.ExternalCombiTable2D(
    "A'_Coefficient",
    "c:\\temp\\data.txt",
    fill(0.0, 0, 2),
    Modelica.Blocks.Types.Smoothness.LinearSegments) "External table object";
  parameter Real x=3 "First coordinate";
  parameter Real y=12 "Second coordinate";
  Real z "Interpolated value at (x,y)";
  equation
    z = Modelica.Blocks.Tables.Internal.getTable2DValue(tableID, x, y);
  annotation(uses(Modelica(version="3.2.3")));
end Model2;
```

Comment: Hi tbeu, i didn't have the chance to check the second model, but if you may please, i posted an answer below, with the the function i was trying to implement. i guess the algorithm behind it is easy. It consists of two different tables A and B. the only two parameters is "angle" and "radius" which are my input. Is everything okay with it ? At the end i want to call this function in a model with my input(angle, radius).

Comment: I want to call it more than once actually, and everytime with different input. So whats better make it a function or a model ?

Answer (score 0):

`function TestBend`

```
input Real angle;
input Real radius;
output Real coefficient_a;
output Real  coefficient_b;

 Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable2D A_Coefficient(fileName = "C:\Users\AWH7RNG\Desktop\a_data.txt", smoothness = Modelica.Blocks.Types.Smoothness.ContinuousDerivative, tableName = "A'_Coefficient", tableOnFile = true)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-10, 54}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));


  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression Radius_A(y = radius)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-62, 64}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression Angle_A(y = angle)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-62, 32}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
 Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable2D B_Coefficient(fileName = "C:\Users\AWH7RNG\Desktop\b_data.txt", tableName = "B_Coefficient")  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {4, -20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
 Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression Radius_B(y = radius)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-56, -8}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
 Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression Angle_B(y = angle)  annotation(
Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-56, -32}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
algorithm
radius := Radius_B.y;
angle :=  Angle_A.y ;
angle := Angle_B.y;
radius := Radius_A.y;
coefficient_a := A_Coefficient.y;
coefficient_b := B_Coefficient.y;
equation
connect(Angle_B.y, B_Coefficient.u2) annotation(
Line(points = {{-44, -32}, {-24, -32}, {-24, -26}, {-8, -26}, {-8, -26}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
connect(Radius_B.y, B_Coefficient.u1) annotation(
Line(points = {{-44, -8}, {-22, -8}, {-22, -14}, {-8, -14}, {-8, -14}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
 connect(Angle_A.y, A_Coefficient.u2) annotation(
Line(points = {{-51, 32}, {-37, 32}, {-37, 48}, {-21, 48}, {-21, 48}, {-23, 48}, {-23, 48}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
 connect(Radius_A.y, A_Coefficient.u1) annotation(
Line(points = {{-51, 64}, {-35, 64}, {-35, 60}, {-21, 60}, {-21, 60}, {-23, 60}, {-23, 60}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
annotation(
uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")));


end TestBend;
```